# Слипаются блоки не хватает места bootsarap 4

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

Здравствуйте учусь верстать на bootstrap 4. Нужно сверстать блок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]на картинке 
Но блоки почему то слипаются когда ширина экрана 990px. Как сделать правильно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
        }
        html {
            max-width: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 100%)));
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        body {
            max-width: calc(100vw - ((100vw - 100%)));
        }
        section{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 90px 20px;
        }
        .content{
            max-width: 1170px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
    
        }
        .grayHeader{
            font-size: 36px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            color: #494d55;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .underHeader{
            color: #a2a6af;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
            text-align: center;
        .description{
            text-align: center;
            color: #494d55;
            font-style: 14px;
        }
        }
        .section4{
            background: #f5f5f5;
        }
        .imgProfile img{
            height: 120px;
            width: 120px;
        }
        .imgProfile{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .profile{
            background: white;
            padding: 30px;
            width: 370px;
            height: 490px;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/stylesForNew.css">
            <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         
            <section class="section4">
                <div class="container justify-content-center">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <p class="grayHeader">Our Team</p>
                            <p class="underHeader">See who are behind AppKit</p>
                            <p class="description">AppKit is created by Xiaoying Riley and Tomasz Najdek. Xiaoying and Tom got to know each other while working as freelancers on Google projects and became good friends. They firmly believe with the right resource, solopreneurs and small teams can execute beautiful products too. Thus they made AppKit to help developers and startups make <br> outstanding products - the internet has made it possible for the "small guys" to compete directly with the "big guys".</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex flex-wrap">
                            <div class="row justify-content-end">
                                <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-10"> 
                                    <div class="profile">
                                        <div class="imgProfile">
                                            <img src="assets/images/team-1.png" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>        
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 d-flex flex-wrap">
                            <div class="row justify-content-start">
                                <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-10">        
                                    <div class="profile">
                                        <div class="imgProfile">
                                            <img src="assets/images/team-2.png" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                            </div>        
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </section>
            
            <script src="assets/js/jsForNew.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все было проще простого при 990px я просто задал уменьшение содержимого блоков и они больше не слипались. Я потратил на эту ошибку 5 вечеров

Comment: Если проблема решена, то вы можете отметить данный (ваш) ответ как принятый.